# Export Content to MS Word document in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, ms-word, export, export-to-word

Hi I am using cakephp to export page content to MS word document.
This thing is completely new for me i have not done this before in any language.
So far after searching on google i could not found much about this.
However I found an artical like this.

‘word’ layout:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past - so must always re-read
header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=myfile.doc"); //this will be the name of the file the user downloads
echo $content_for_layout; ?>
```

Controller Function:

```
function printToWord($pageId) {
    $page = $this->Customer->findById($pageId);
    $this->set('page',$page);
    $file = new File(APP.DS.'webroot'.DS.'css'.DS.'print.css', false); //1
    $this->set('inlineCss',$file->read()); //2
    $file->close();
    $this->layout = "word";
    Configure::write('debug',0);
}
```

And In View:

```
<style>
<?php if (isset($inlineCss) echo $inlineCss;?>
```

Help me I am disappointed.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you already have a Word document you want to send using your app, or if you want to **create** a Word document dynamically...

If it's the second option, you may want to have a look at PHPOffice/PHPWord which is a library in PHP to read and write Word documents.

It's very well documented and will probably solve your problem:

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Hope this helps,

**UPDATE**

Just a few more words (no pun intended...)...

PHPWord has an extensive range of examples in https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/tree/develop/samples

I am pretty sure one of them or a mix will sort out your needs.

Hope this helps,

Comment: The second option ..  I want to create word document dynamically ?
Can you Help me with something else ? @Pbal

Comment: Is this library support MS word ?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman: yes! with this library you can generate Word documents dynamically.  Have a look at the "Getting Started" section.  It's very straight-forward to use.